# SharePoint 2013 - JS link override not always working

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have included a js link override file to a custom list. It is supposed to override the title of an element to set a link to the title. Usually this is working fine, but sometimes it seems like the js link file is not loaded. I've embedded the link to this aspx-page that has my custom list included in the standard Sharepoint navigation. When I open the page the title has no link behind - meaning the js link file is not loaded. In that case I reload the whole aspx-page and then it shows. If I try to reproduce this behavior it is sometimes working fine immediately and sometimes not.

This is may js link file:

```
    (function () {

       var overrideCtx = {};
       overrideCtx.Templates = {};

       overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
       overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;


       overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
         'Title': { 'View' : '<a href="https.myUrl.aspx?ContentArea=<#=ctx.CurrentItem.ID#>"><#=ctx.CurrentItem.Title#></a>' }
       };

      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
    })();
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem necessarily anything wrong with the code itself - although does the custom script (The above) always return a `200 GET Request` even when it *doesn't* work?

Comment: Is the Minimal Download Strategy enabled on your site? (urls that contain /_layouts/15/start.aspx)

Comment: I checked the feature Minimal Download Strategy. After deactivating it, the JS Link worked.

Comment: To make it work with MDS, wrap your code above in a function that you invoke from the IIFE as above, but also call the following at the end of the IIFE: RegisterModuleInit("~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MyCustomRenderListTemplate.js", myCustomOverrideFunctionName);